# Calling function from (Laravel 8) Blade template file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a blade component called OrderBox.php in app/View/Components.
It has several public attributes I can access from the orderbox.blade.php template file.

```
            <x-orderbox
                    :id="$id"
                    ....
            ></x-orderbox>
```

However, there is a public function `getShortTextByStatus($statusCode)` in the OrderBox.php component file
and when I call this function **inside orderbox.blade.php** template

```
{{ $getShortTextByStatus('EDIT') }}
```

I get the *Undefined variable: shortTextByStatus* error

I followed this: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#component-methods
but everything looks the same, what am I missing?

**EDIT:**

If I remove the $ I get the *Call to undefined function getShortTextByStatus()* error

```
{{ getShortTextByStatus('EDIT') }}
```

OrderBox.php

```
class OrderBox extends Component
{

    public $id;
    ....

    public function __construct()
    {
    //
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.orderbox');
    }

    public function getShortTextByStatus($statusCode)
    {
       return 'TEST';
    }

}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I noticed that x-orderbox actually should be x-order-box

```
<x-order-box
    :id="$id"
     ....
></x-order-box>
```

With this, the {{ $getShortTextByStatus("EDIT") }} works !

B U T

does not pass attributes like
:id="$id"
or

```
something="static"
```

So the public $id; or public $something will be empty....

Comment: Can you share `OrderBox.php`?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto - please see the updated question

Comment: @GJasonSharma - I do call it from inside, I highlighted that part of the text

Comment: Looks like your component is fine

Comment: "I get the Undefined variable: shortTextByStatus error" is this a typo in your question or in your code? `$getShortTextByStatus()` instead of `$shortTextByStatus()` you need the `$` for these functions.

Comment: @GertB. - thanks, it was a typo in my question, corrected now

Comment: Have you tried renaming it to something _not_ starting with `get`? Might confuse Laravel. Just a guess

Comment: @brombeer that could be the problem indeed. I was really wondering why the code did not work as is

Comment: @brombeer - actually I have tried, same thing, error thrown

Comment: To pass the `$id` using `:id` you have to pass it in your constructor: `public function __construct($id) {` and set it using `$this->id = id;`

Answer (score 0):

So I made a couple of mistakes here

First of all, if the component name is **OrderBox** than the

tag should be

```
<x-order-box></x-order-box>
```

And then, if you want to pass data to the component (OrdeBox) you need
to add the attributes to the constructor - special thanks to @gert-b (Gert B)
from the comment section

```
class OrderBox extends Component
{

    public $id;
    public $otherId;
    ....

    public function __construct($id, $otherId)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->otherId;
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

For some reason, I thought only mandatory attributes go to the constructor.

And don't forget, the attributes in the component class are camelCase
like public $otherId; but in the template, it is kebab case: other-id

```
<x-order-box
    id="1"
    :other-id="$someVariable"
></x-order-box>
```